# Changing shapefile encoding using Python

Tags: python, shapefile, ogr2ogr

I have shapefile in `cp1251` and trying to convert it into `utf-8`.

1. Create `cpg` file with text `cp1251` with same name as my shapefile and put it in same directory.
2. Run `ogr2ogr -lco ENCODING=UTF8 output.shp input.shp` and got shape file in needed `utf-8` encoding.

Now i want to do the same using Python.

1. Download svn.osgeo.org/gdal/trunk/gdal/swig/python/samples/ogr2ogr.py
2. Run

```py
import ogr2ogr
ogr2ogr.main(["", "-f", "ESRI Shapefile","-lco", "ENCODING=UTF8", output_file_shp, file_shp ])
```

But in this case encoding didn't change. Did I forget something or am I using a wrong method?

Comment: Shapefile tests in the autotest suite https://github.com/OSGeo/gdal/blob/master/autotest/ogr/ogr_shape.py are using `UTF-8` but if UTF8 works on the command line why not with Python. Have a try. The properly maintained ogr2ogr in Python is gdal.VectorTranslate, find usage examples from autotests https://github.com/OSGeo/gdal/blob/master/autotest/utilities/test_ogr2ogr_lib.py

Comment: Works for me. Does it return `True` for you or give an error? Sure you've got your `output_file_shp` and `file_shp` correct? I'm running it thus: `ogr2ogr.main(["","-f","ESRI Shapefile","-lco" ,"ENCODING=UTF8", "out2.shp","out.shp"])` in the folder where those shapefiles are. It only changes `out2.cpg` as expected.

Comment: I believe that the strings in .dbf should be changed as well. From the documentation `An attempt is made to read the code page setting in the .cpg file, or as a fallback in the LDID/codepage setting from the .dbf file, and use it to translate string fields to UTF-8 on read, and back when writing.`